# XSLT Split children into new nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform the structure of an XML file and figured XSLT might be the best solution (that's what it's for right?) I have some experience with XSLT but it is slightly limited so I need some guidance.

The scenario is as follows; I have an XML containing one or more records. Each record has a set of fields and each field has a set of sub fields. The order of the sub fields is significant. What needs to be done is that the input structure needs to be transformed so that each occurrence of sub field codes A and K should result in a new field (with a new code and sub field K renamed to A) in the output with the sub fields that follows either sub field A or K, as the example below illustrates. The number of sub fields K is arbitrary and may differ from record to record the the xslt need to be slightly general.

Here is my input XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <record>
      <field code="123">
         <subfield code="A">Abc</subfield>
         <subfield code="B">De</subfield>
         <subfield code="K">Fgh</subfield>
         <subfield code="C">IJ</subfield>
         <subfield code="K">Klmn</subfield>
         <subfield code="D">OP</subfield>
     </field>
     <field>... more datafields... </field>
   </record>
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <record>
      <field code="124">
         <subfield code="A">Abc</subfield>
         <subfield code="B">De</subfield>   
     </field>
     <field code="124">
         <subfield code="A">Fgh</subfield>
         <subfield code="C">IJ</subfield>
     </field>
     <field code="124">
         <subfield code="A">Klmn</subfield>
         <subfield code="D">OP</subfield>
     </field>
     <field>... more datafields... </field>
   </record>
```

If anyone can provide me with some sample xslt that at least points me in the right direction I would me much obliged.

EDIT: Just to clarify. There can be any number of sub fields between the A and K sub fields.

Comment: The input has `field code="123"`, why does the output have `field code="124"`? And can you use XSLT 2.0? It looks like a good job for using `<xsl:template match="field"><xsl:for-each-group select="subfield" group-starting-with="subfield[@code = ('A', 'K')]">...`.

Comment: Is it *every odd subfield* that needs to be paired with the following even one, or *every A or K subfield*? Or is that the same thing?

Comment: @MartinHonnen field code="124" is correct in the output. It is a format translation so to speak. I'm writing this in Visual Studio 2012 not sure about XSLT 2.0 support. Will need to look into that.

Comment: @michael.hor257k every A or K should result in a new field with code 124. The input can only have one occurrence of sub field A but multiple occurrences of sub field K.

Comment: @EmilTinebo, there are third party XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9 in a .NET version, XmlPrime or AltovaXML but Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform or MSXML only support XSLT 1.0.

Comment: *"There can be any number of sub fields between the A and K sub fields."*  This is still not quite clear, I am afraid: are all subfields [not (A or K)] following an A or a K to be grouped together with the leading A or K? Also, is there only one record in the input? And only one field code=123 that needs to processed in this way?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sub field A is always the first sub field and the sub field can only contain one sub field a. Sub field K is to be treated as a Sub field a but because of the restriction of only one sub field A sub field code K is used instead. There can be multiple records in the output and each record in the input can only contain one field with code=123. This gives that all sub fields between sub field A and K should result in a new field 124 with the selected sub fields. Same thing for sub fiels between first K and second K and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or Altova or XmlPrime you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="subfield" group-starting-with="subfield[@code = ('A', 'K')]">
    <field code="124">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </field>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subfield/@code[. = 'K']">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="'A'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <record>
      <field code="123">
         <subfield code="A">Abc</subfield>
         <subfield code="B">De</subfield>
         <subfield code="K">Fgh</subfield>
         <subfield code="C">IJ</subfield>
         <subfield code="K">Klmn</subfield>
         <subfield code="D">OP</subfield>
     </field>
     <field>... more datafields... </field>
   </record>
```

into

```
<record>
   <field code="124">
      <subfield code="A">Abc</subfield>
      <subfield code="B">De</subfield>
   </field>
   <field code="124">
      <subfield code="A">Fgh</subfield>
      <subfield code="C">IJ</subfield>
   </field>
   <field code="124">
      <subfield code="A">Klmn</subfield>
      <subfield code="D">OP</subfield>
   </field>
</record>
```

If you need an XSLT 1.0 solution then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sub" match="subfield[not(@code = 'A' or @code = 'K')]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::subfield[@code = 'A' or @code = 'K'][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code = 'A' or @code = 'K']" mode="group"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subfield[@code = 'A' or @code = 'K']" mode="group">
  <field code="124">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | key('sub', generate-id())"/>
  </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subfield/@code[. = 'K']">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">A</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do.

Comment: Based on your latest explanation it might be that in case of `template match="field"` you would need `template match="field[@code = 23]"`, it shouldn't be too difficult to change that if you only want to transform those field elements.

Comment: This almost worked. The sub field codes in my new 124 fields turned up as K and not A... not sure why... any clues?

Comment: Please explain in more details as to what you have tried now, the XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, the XSLT 2.0 one, the input as shown or something different? With my samples doing `<xsl:template match="subfield/@code[. = 'K']"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}">A</xsl:attribute>` I don't see why you would get `K` and not `A`.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I tried the XSLT 1.0 version. Running the XSLT from visual studio the break point in the template `<xsl:template match="subfield/@code[. = 'K']">` is never hit...

Comment: I have another template that seems to be running instead of the one you provided... `<xsl:template match="subfield">
    <subfield>
      <xsl:call-template name="copyAttributes"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </subfield>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="copyAttributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: Well my stylesheet does its job, I have just tested it in VS 2012. If you make changes or add templates you are on your own, the template for the attribute will of course only be "called" if the other templates ensure an `apply-templates select="@*` is done. My sample does that, I am not sure why you think you need your other templates. As long as the first template in my samples, the identity transformation template is present, any copying is done for nodes which don't have and need a more specific template,

Comment: You're right. Your stylesheet did it's job. I missed the `apply-templates select="@*` part Thank you very much! Accepting this answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

<xsl:template match="subfield">
    <field code="{../@code}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::subfield[1]" />
    </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//subfield[position() mod 2 = 1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```